# Address Search for the Google Map widget on App Maker

Tags: google-maps, google-app-maker

I see the Google Map widget documentation for App Maker says I can bind a [datasource](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/display-widgets#google-map) to it so that user can input an address to update the map.
Is it possible to bind it to something like a [Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) in App Maker?

It'd be great if I don't need to create my own datasource to enable an address search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build Address Search using [Suggest Box](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#suggest-box), [Calculated Datasource](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated) and [Geocoder Apps Script service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/geocoder)

```js
/**
 * Creates address suggestion record.
 * @param {Object} geocode Geocode object received from Maps Geocoder.
 * @return {AddressSuggestion} Created suggestion record.
 */
function createAddressSuggestion_(geocode) {
  var record = app.models.AddressSuggestion.newRecord();
  record.Address = geocode.formatted_address;
  return record;
}


/**
 * Gets address suggestions Maps Geocoder.
 * @param {string} term Start of address string to search for.
 * @return {Array<AddressSuggestion>} Array of suggestion records.
 */
function getAddressSuggestions_(term) {
  // TODO: Uncomment to set clientId and Google Maps API Key
  // Maps.setAuthentication('your_client_id', 'your_signing_key');

  var response = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(term);
  var geocodes = response.results;

  return geocodes.map(createAddressSuggestion_);
}
```

[image: Datasource]

One more **important** important thing: you need to say Suggest Box to handle your datasource as whole records otherwise it will filter out all results that have no exact match with your `_startsWith` term:
[image: Record as value]

Answer (score 0):

To complete Pavel Shkleinik answer,

We do not need to authenticate using the Maps.setAuthentication('your_client_id', 'your_signing_key');

see here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setAuthentication(String,String)
This method doesn't work with API keys. Additionally, please note that Premium Plan is no longer available for new customers. If you don't already have a Premium Plan license, please don't call setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey). You are able to use the Maps methods with the default quota allowances.

Also, I had to use a default value for the Address field the auto-complete to work. If I didn't use a default value, the Query would return a null.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA4Nx.png)