# How do I bind the value from the Address suggest box to the customer's Address field?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker, suggestbox

I have an input form in App Maker that a user can enter contact information for projects we're working on (name, phone number, email and address), that works fine but I wanted to implement a better way to input addresses. All that contact info is bound to the Projects datasource (including the Address field).

So, I created an address suggestion box according to these instructions: [Address Search for the Google Map widget on App Maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817723/address-search-for-the-google-map-widget-on-app-maker?rq=1) (I don't have enough reputation to comment there).

That seems to works fine but I am not able to set the selected address from that suggestBox to @datasource.item.Address. When I open the binding options all the items are grayed out, I cannot select anything. Even if I try @datasources.Projects.Item.Address I still show all options grayed out. How can I bind the suggested address to the Address field in my Projects datasource?

I assume there would be some code I could put into the suggestBox onValueChange event that would copy the newValue from the box to the Address field but I'm not having much luck with that. I did some research and came across that newValue field, I tried this bit of code to try to copy that over. No luck.

```
    widget.datasource.item.Address = newValue;
widget.datasource.createItem();
```

[image: Binding options grayed out]

Comment: I think you should use `items`

Comment: Can't do that either, I should have specified that. Everything under items is also grayed out, can't select anything there.

Comment: So after some more research it looks like you cannot bind the suggest box value field because it is dynamic, depending on what suggestion the user selects. What I need to figure out is how to take that value and copy it over to the Address field of the Project datasource. I've tried more code, spent hours online researching and trying different things, just can't get it to work. Any ideas?